# Cannot compile the ring crate: file not found for module `montgomery`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Cargo is not compiling with the following error:

```
$ cargo build
Compiling ring v0.12.1
error[E0583]: file not found for module `montgomery`
    --> 
 C:\Users\jmccrae\.cargo\registry\src\github.com1ecc6299db9ec823\ring-0.12.1\src\arithmetic/arithmetic.rs:15:9
   |
15 | pub mod montgomery;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: name the file either arithmetic\montgomery.rs or arithmetic\montgomery\mod.rs inside the directory 
"C:\\Users\\jmccrae\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.12.1\\src\\arithmetic"
```

The project was a new project with Cargo.toml modified to include a dependency to the most recent version (0.12.1) of the `ring` crate. The Cargo.toml is as follows:

```
[package]
name = "testring"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["John McCrae <john@mccr.ae>"]

[dependencies]
ring = "0.12.1"
```

The required file seems to actually exist:

```
$ ls  C:\\Users\\jmccrae\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\ring-0.12.1\\src\\arithmetic
arithmetic.rs  montgomery.rs
```

The cargo version is `cargo 0.25.0-nightly (930f9d949 2017-12-05)` and it is running on MINGW.

Is there anything wrong with the compiler set-up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [an issue with Ring and Rust 1.24.0-nightly (2017-12-21)](https://github.com/briansmith/ring/issues/598). It also has an associated [issue in the Rust repository](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/46936).

To work around it, use an older version of Rust nightly (or avoid nightly if you can).

Comment: Rocket always requires the latest version of Rust nightly. How can I use the older version of Rust?

Comment: @kin you need to wait until Rocket and Ring have upgraded to the newest nightly.

Comment: OK. Thank you. It seems that it is not production ready. Does it built in session like `session_start` in PHP?