# Unable to build Rocket.rs: The given version requirement is invalid

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-rocket

I am following [the Rocket getting started guide](https://rocket.rs/guide/getting-started/) to learn the Rocket web framework for Rust. When I execute `cargo run --verbose` I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\kin\Desktop\hello-rocket> cargo run --verbose
Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
failed to parse registry's information for: serde

Caused by:
  the given version requirement is invalid
```

#### System details

```
Desktop Environment:   Windows 10
Cargo Version      :   cargo 0.8.0-nightly (28a0cbb 2016-01-17)
rustc Version      :   rustc 1.7.0 (a5d1e7a59 2016-02-29)
```

#### Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "hello-rocket"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["XXX"]

[dependencies]
rocket = "0.3.5"
rocket_codegen = "0.3.5"
```

Comment: The best place to ask this question is the [rocket issues page](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket).

Comment: What version of Rust?  What version of Cargo?  What's in `Cargo.toml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Uninstall Rust language in your PC
- Go to [the Rust official website](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/install.html) to download and reinstall the latest Rust.

Answer (score 2):

> I am following the Rocket getting started guide

The [very first section of the guide you linked](https://rocket.rs/guide/getting-started/#installing-rust) to states (emphasis mine):

> Rocket makes abundant use of Rust’s syntax extensions and other advanced, unstable features. Because of this, we’ll need to **use a nightly version of Rust**.

Slightly later, it states:

> Rocket always requires the **latest version of Rust nightly**.

Yet you have a stable version of Rust (1.7.0); one that is almost **22 months old** at this point (2016-02-29). Rust 1.22.1 is the current stable version of Rust.

The guide continues on to describe how to install the latest nightly; I suggest following it.

Comment: Unable to upgrade Rustc by using `rustup update` in Windows PowerShell. I finally solved it by reinstall Rust using the `rustup‑init.exe` installer.

Comment: This time I encountered the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941738/cannot-compile-the-ring-crate-file-not-found-for-module-montgomery